# Running time for this for loop statement?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to figure out the Big-O run time for this loop statement. Can somebody help me out?

`for (i = 1; i < n*n; i=i*2)`

Is it `O(n^2 lg n)`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it should be `O(logn)`. Because `log(n^2) = O(logn)`.

Answer (score 2):

Its O(logn) :

```
log(n^2) = 2log(n) = O(logn)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers proposed are correct;
ìt is `O(logn)`, because your iteration increment is polynomial (1, 4, 8, 16 etc..), not linear.

You can look at it like this - the number of iterations is not linear, but polynomial, which is in logaritmic proportion to the amount of iterations. Although the number of iterations is quadratic, it is constat during your loop execution, therefore the quantifier `2` in `2*O(logn)` can be ignored.